# outline stroke for text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an outline to text using CSS.

The problem is that the shadow not so good for stroke text perfectly.

Is there any way to do this with pure css ?

Here is my code :

```css
.text-stroke {
  font-size: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px #2d4c79, 
                1px 1px #2d4c79, 
               -2px 2px #2d4c79, 
                2px -1px #2d4c79;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-stroke">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `webkit-text-stroke`

```css
.text-stroke {
  font-size: 200px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-stroke">Text</div>
```

Comment: is this work in Firefox or other browser not use webkit?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome, Firefox, IE edge

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke